# Android app Listview cannot be scrolled to bottom to search a specific element using appium in java

Tags: java, android, appium

Can someone please help me with this.

I am facing an issue - Android app Listview cannot be scrolled to bottom to search a specific element using appium in java

1. code used is :

   ```
        HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();

       RemoteWebElement element = (RemoteWebElement)driver.findElementById(fullListContainer);

       JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       String widId = ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId();

       scrollObject.put("text", tvProvidername);
       scrollObject.put("element", widId);

       js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);

       seleniumFunctions.click(driver, By.name(tvProvidername));
   ```

//element is the Listview

//tvProvidername is the text to be searched while scrolling the Listview

2. Issue Description: The native android app has Listview with more than 280 elements, and the code line 'js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);' just gets executed till 100 elements, it does not scroll to more than 100th element in the app as a result when an element after 100th element is searched, script fails.

Thanks,
NRM

Answer (score 0):

I was able to scroll down in list view to find a specific element using below strategy, hope this helps...(you can use findElementByText as well)

```
boolean token = false;
while(!token) {
    try {
        if (driver.findElementByID(cellId).isDisplayed()) {
            token = true;
            System.Out.println("Cell Found;");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

        int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
        int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
        int x = size.width / 2;

        //Vertical scrolling down
        driver.swipe(x, starty, x, endy, 4000);
        continue;
    }
}
```